# First steps in Designers World

Tags: website-design, education

My question is simple so feel free to give me any kind of suggestion.
I want to study as a Designer and I'm expecially oriented in Web Design.
I don't have any graphical studies in my carrier and now I'm a Computer Engineer student. 
I really want to know were to begin my studies in this fascinating world so I will really appreciate your suggestions on "where to start".

Thanks all for your time.

Best regards,

Luca

Comment: your Q looks too broad to me...

Comment: Stay out whilst you're still sane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- Get a degree. Consider degrees in Graphic Design, User Experience, Library Sciences, Product Design, Service Design, etc.
- Continuing education. Consider classes at Lynda.com or the like. Maybe a school that offers web based classes.
- DIY/On your own. Just start designing. Practice, practice, practice. Read, read, read. Slowly build up a portfolio of projects for friends and family/personal projects. This is the hardest route, but easiest to start with.
- Find an internship. Likely won't make much money. But will get hands up experience/mentoring.

Comment: Hello DA01, I really apprecciate your answer to my "broad question" (I need to admit that it's too much "generic"). I know the famous portal "Lynda.com" but there are so many course that I can't know where to start. I really need to consider the degree option. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you can swing it, the degree option will likely be the most rewarding of the experiences. A good art/design school is really a great place to spend a few years. (Just stay away from the Graphic Design Logo-mills...there are a lot of for-profit community colleges that offer GD degrees that aren't worth much. Do try and find a reputable art school)